# PhoneFactory.getDefaultphone in android

Tags: android

I am trying to call PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone from a new
 application so that I can access its invokeOemRilRaw* functions. But
 it gives me a  "java.lang.RuntimeException:
 PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone must be called from Looper thread" error.

Is this possible ? Or is this function dedicated for the PhoneApp
 only ?

Regards,

vinila

Answer (score 0):

It's an internal API and you can't access it from your process.